# quering four tables in mysql usin java

Tags: java, mysql

I have four tables named result1, result2, result3 and result4 all having same columns as (rollno int, name varchar(20), marks int, year int).

I want to get rollno and names of students having marks greater than 60 in year 2012 in all the four tables and display it in a single table. I am not getting the logic to check marks in all four tables simultaneously. Please help. 
I am using java and mysql to code.

Comment: Why not use single table ??

Comment: In the unlikely event that there is a good reason for using separate tables, see UNION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `union all` operator allows you to concatinate query results. So, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT rollno, name
FROM   (SELECT * FROM result1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM result2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM result3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM result4) t
WHERE  mark > 60 AND year = 2012
```